# How to execute some code at last retry of a Celery task

Tags: django, celery, background-task

I am using Django with Celery to run my background tasks. I have a task that can fail for some IO reasons:

```py
@shared_task(bind=True)
def mytask(self, someargs):
  try:
    do_some_io_operation()
  except SomeException as e:
    self.retry(max_retries=5)

  # do some other stuff
```

I want to execute some code **only** if the last retry fails and exit the function without raising an exception.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I actually found the answer in [another ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27950963/how-to-keep-track-of-retries-in-celery):

```py
@shared_task(bind=True)
def mytask(self, someargs):
  max_retries = 5
  try:
    do_some_io_operation()
  except SomeException as e:

    if (self.request.retries >= max_retries):
      # do some stuff
      return

    self.retry(max_retries=max_retries)

  # do some other stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an exception:

`from celery.exceptions import Retry, MaxRetriesExceededError`

so the code may look like:

```
@shared_task(bind=True)
def mytask(self, someargs):
  try:
     try:
       do_some_io_operation()
     except SomeException as e:
       self.retry(max_retries=5)

     # do some other stuff
  except MaxRetriesExceededError:
     # delicately finish operations / close connections
```